# Are images received in Line messaging app saved without download?

Tags: images, line

Does LINE app automatically save the received images or only the ones we click save. 
If It saves without saving than where can I find these?

Comment: Well, it's saved in device temporary storage folder, I mean it will show up for sometime but eventually when the conversation gets old they are likely to overwritten by something else, or if you use cleaner apps it going to clean those images out eventually and tapping the save button would take it to the device permanent storage ! :)